# Modify the type of a column in multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the same attribute in several of my tables in my database, this attribute is called `address` and it is of type `string`, how can I change it to be of type `text`, but I want to do this in multiple tables

Is there any way I can make all these changes in the same migration?

```
class ChangeTypeAddressPlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    change_table :precints do |t|
      t.change :address, :text
    end

    change_table :precint_events do |t|
      t.change :address, :text
    end

    change_table :precint_translations do |t|
      t.change :address, :text
    end

    change_table :locations do |t|
      t.change :address, :text
    end

    change_table :location_events do |t|
      t.change :address, :text
    end

    change_table :location_translations do |t|
      t.change :address, :text
    end
  end

  def down
    change_table :precints do |t|
      t.change :address, :string
    end

    change_table :precint_events do |t|
      t.change :address, :string
    end

    change_table :precint_translations do |t|
      t.change :address, :string
    end

    change_table :locations do |t|
      t.change :address, :string
    end

    change_table :location_events do |t|
      t.change :address, :string
    end

    change_table :location_translations do |t|
      t.change :address, :string
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `change_column` migration method to be more concise. Your migration would look something like this example below. I would recommend reading through the [Active Record Migration Docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#changing-columns) as well.

```
def up
  change_column :precints, :address, :text
  change_column :precint_events, :address, :text
  change_column :precint_translations, :address, :text
  change_column :locations, :address, :text
  change_column :location_events, :address, :text
  change_column :location_translations, :address, :text
end

def down
  change_column :precints, :address, :string
  change_column :precint_events, :address, :string
  change_column :precint_translations, :address, :string
  change_column :locations, :address, :string
  change_column :location_events, :address, :string
  change_column :location_translations, :address, :string
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class ChangeTypeAddressPlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  TABLES = [:precints, :precint_events, :precint_translations,                   
            :locations, :location_events, :location_translations]
  def up
    TABLES.each { |table| change_column table, :address, :text }
  end

  def down
    TABLES.each { |table| change_column table, :address, :string }
  end
end
```